# Sublime Text building does not find SDL directory

Tags: build, sdl, sublimetext2

Trying to lead the build system on Sublime to my SDL directory but won't compile

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "-L/usr/include/SDL", "-lSDLmain", "-lSDL", "-lSDL_ttf", "-lSDL_image"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
    }
]
}
```

Keep getting all my calls to SDL returned undefined references. Can't seem to get the directory called correctly on the command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using incorrect path for the linker. In `/usr/include/` there are only header files.

So I suppose you should modify it the following way :

```
-L<Where libraries are placed>
```

E.g. in Ubuntu:

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu // 64 bit libraries
-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu   // 32 bit libraries
```

In order to let the compiler new header directory you should use `-I` flag:

```
-I/usr/include
```

Comment: Is that the standard install directory for SDL libs? Leading the compiler to that directory gives me the same undefined references

Comment: @Pendertuga No, it is not a default. It can depend on how did you installed it in the system.

Comment: Alright, I changed the -L directory to where the lib files are which is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` but now I'm getting that the header files are not found when I link to that directory.

Comment: @Pendertuga, for adding your header path, you should use the `-I` flag.